# Passing information between Java LoginModules (Generic Map Problem)

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, jaas

I am currently trying to write some LoginModules to enable users to log into a Java application.  Here is my .java.login.config file:

```
"Java Application" {
    path.to.login.module.PamLoginModule   sufficient;
    path.to.login.module.OtherLoginModule sufficient;
};
```

So if the PamLoginModule fails, I want to pass information to the OtherLoginModule.  This way, the OtherLoginModule doesn't have to ask for the user name and password again.  So I am guessing that this is what the sharedState Map is for in the initialize() function:

```
initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, 
           Map<String,?> sharedState, Map<String,?> options)
```

The problem is that you can't put things into the sharedState map.  If I do something like:

```
sharedState.put("key", value); // Value is a string
```

The compiler complains:

```
path/to/login/module/PamLoginModule.java:48: put(java.lang.String,capture#833 of ?) in java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture#833 of ?> cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    this.sharedState.put("key", value);
```

I have found a way to get around this, but I want to know what the correct way is.

First, I can use the java 1.4.2 version of initialize which is:

```
initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map sharedState, Map options)
```

This way I just receive generic maps and I can just cast the Map object to a Map

```
Map<String,Object> this.sharedState = (Map<String,Object>)sharedState;
```

The problem is that I still get unchecked cast exceptions.  Now, I know the people who made the LoginModule interface aren't stupid, so I am wondering why they made the sharedState map a `Map<String,?>` as opposed to a `Map<String,Object>`.  Also, is there a better way to put things into the sharedState map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the LoginModule implementations in the Java SDK, they save those maps into local fields without the *generics* info, that is plain Maps. And in the code they do put objects there (at least when the user is authenticated). So the use of the question mark in the LoginModule interface has to be a design mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering why they made the
>   sharedState map a `Map<String,?>` as
>   opposed to a `Map<String,Object>`.

This is exactly what I'm wondering.
I guess the purpose of using `?` is to accept anything (I don't really see another explanation), so using Object would be completely right and standard.

If you're posting here I guess you cannot ask who coded it this way (using `?`) to know why.
Therefore you should investigate a bit the related classes/methods to discover if there is really a meaningful and specific use for `?`. Otherwise you should make it a `<String, Object`>.

I've personnally never seen that current use, except when `?` is specified as `<? implements MyInterface>` or `<T extends MySuperClass>` for example. In the first case, you should be able to do `Map<String, MyInterface>` anyway with the same result.

Sorry if I don't have a specific answer but I hope this helps you!